# Triggering an event after rotating image with CropperJS

Tags: cropperjs

I'm trying to trigger an event handler after a CropperJS image is rotated or zoomed, similar to how the "cropend" event gets triggered after the image is dragged within the crop window.

Is this possible with CropperJS?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's possible.

Here is how I resolved this issue. I had to perform one action after multiple events.

```js
var image = document.getElementById('demo');

// declare event handler before cropper init
$(image).on('ready zoom', function () {
   // do common things here
});

new Cropper(image, {
    ready: function () {
       // do something here
    },
    zoom: function () {
       // do something here
    },
    // ...other events
});
```

Is this what you're asking about?